# How to convert Mysql BLOB into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have already built database with field BLOB containing following raw data.

```
<i>a:34:{s:5:"stype";s:1:"1";s:9:"studentid";s:4:"1105";s:18:"duration_of_course";s:7:"2 years";s:22:"applicant_name_surname";s:15:"Tsering Kunchok";s:17:"course_or_subject";s:16:"Computer </i>
```

How can I retrieve data in PHP one dimension?

Comment: $array  = json_decode($variable);

Comment: Looks like the result of [serialize](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) has been stored in the database -> http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: @Naveed Ramzan  it's not json.

Comment: Try this

    $array = explode(',', $youvariable);

Comment: @shivachauhan explode function isn't giving me an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
<?php

var_dump(unserialize('a:34:{s:5:"stype";s:1:"1";s:9:"studentid";s:4:"1105";s:18:"duration_of_course";s:7:"2 years";s:22:"applicant_name_surname";s:15:"Tsering Kunchok";s:17:"course_or_subject";s:16:"Computer"') );
```

Do not forget to load dependencies used for serialization ...

Comment: Its working now. Cool...